# what is output of -mzeep --profile?

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I am writing a saop client in python and zeep and I am playing with the -mzeep tool. It has an option --profile [filename]. Does anybody know the output file's format or what it is for? The documentation says only this: *--profile PROFILE  Enable profiling and save output to given file.*
I was not able to find any more info. The file seems to be a binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/releases), it seems to be doing this:

```
if args.profile:
    import cProfile

    profile = cProfile.Profile()
    profile.enable()
```

cProfile is one of the [Python profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), so the output file must be specific to cProfile. The [Stats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-stats-class) class can read it and allow you to print various details from it.